# Conditional Formatting and/or Formula Issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I stop a cell from changing color when it has a value of "<1%". This is the formula in the cell, 
=IF(C$19=0%,0%,IF(C$19<0.99%,"<1%",ROUNDDOWN(C$19,2))).

I have conditional formatting in the cell; (Rule#1 A1>=80% - Show orange, Rule#2 A1>=95% show Red)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. If you have conditional formatting for ">80%", then a cell with "<1%" will not be colored. Is that what you want? What do you mean by "stop from changing color"?

Comment: Yes, I agree the cell shouldn't be colored, but for some reason that I can't seem to figure out it is. The cell shows the color of rule# 2 (red).
@Sir Adelaide

Comment: OK. Well, from what you write it should not be colored - so there must be something wrong. I think you'll have to provide your Excel file (or a simplified version) showing the problem - I don't see how we can help otherwise.

Comment: Maybe the cell is simply set to a color. It keeps that color unless a rule changes it.

Comment: It is colored red because, the way Excel does comparisons, any string will be greater than a number.  `"<1%"` is a **string**, not a **number**, so it will always be greater than 95%.  You can either set a specific format for that string, as described by @yass, or you can use custom formatting to store the actual numeric value, but display it as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Rule for "<1%" and use no color for it
Enter Manage Rules and at the same Row of this rule Click `Stop if True`

Comment: Thank You @Yass. It took a little massaging but I was able to get it.

Comment: Sure because you need to treat "<1%" as string that is why I wrote it between "